# Экран tinymce черный

Tags: tinymce

Не виден текст. Синие ссылки видны. Перезагрузка и смена на ckeditor не помогли.
Может быть, кто-нибудь сталкивался? Подскажите.

Comment: Монитор включить пробовали?

Без шуток - выкладывайте ваш код или опишите, что и как меняли, когда размещали эти редакторы и где именно их размещаете. Чем больше расскажете, тем быстрее найдется ответ.

@romb, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Мне почему-то кажется, что причина в `background: #000000;`. Пользуйтесь консолью браузера, посмотрите стили, ошибки js и т.д.

Comment: Действительно так, на всех страницах фон черный background #черный - но как решить проблему в редакторе. Стили в редакторе я не трогал. И вообще не пользуюсь установекми в редакторе - не рекомендуется, редактор установлен еще 3 месяца назад, все было N.

Comment: Способ 1: смотрите, в какой элементе именно проблемы и применяйте к нему свой стиль с пометкой `important`. Если проблемный элемент внутри iframe, см. 2

Способ 2: как применить css к тексту внутри tiny: [см. оф. докумментацию](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:content_css).

Comment: Прокомментировал ответ выше. 

> не пользуюсь установекми в редакторе -не рекомендуется

Кем не рекомендуется? Что там у вас такое, что его трогать нельзя?

P. S. Я стараюсь по-максимуму перевести всех своих пользователей с WYSIWYG на markdown. Пока вроде получается

Comment: мзменил бакгроунд на белый и экран в редакторе тоже стал белый.Подскажите где эта связь находится -может быть удасться разорвать.

Comment: Какой бекграунд вы изменили? Я не телепат, без кода вашего ничего не скажу. А связь очень простая: поменяли цвет в css — поменялся цвет объекта. Оно, какбы, для того и существует =)

Comment: Да конечно, реальность хороша в меру, что-то должно быть абстрактным.

Comment: Это не ваша статья miw.by/1429

Comment: да,все времятак у меня,извините.
Изменил цвет фона страниц сайта на белый в файлах css на сайте. 
Но одновременно изменился цвет экрана редактора,стал виден темный текст на белом фоне . где то связь . В настройках редактора CMS ничего подходящего.

Тогда пойду менять стили самого редактора ,по Вашему совету.

Comment: @romb 

    tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        content_css : "/mycontent.css"
    });

mycontent.css:

    html, body {
        background: white;
        color: black;
    }

    a {
        color: blue;
    }

Попробуйте, работает ли?